# What does 'material advantage' mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I looked up the word in a number of dictionaries, but I am not sure which is its definition. Does it mean ***important***, or ***physical***, or ***else***?

> Not all clothing has to be made of woven materials, of course. It’s
> likely that for a very long time people made do with draped animal
> pelts and then began roughly sewing these together(although they would
> perhaps have used fibrous thread to do so). Ultimately, though, the
> advantages of using woven fabric for clothing would have become
> obvious. A fur pelt offers excellent thermal protection if someone is
> sitting still or lying down, but once on the move or in strong winds,
> this is less true, because pelts aren’t shaped close to the body. The
> more air gets between the body and the clothing, the less effective it
> is at trapping an insulating layer of air close to the skin. In fact,
> the isolating properties of clothing decrease very much when walking
> briskly. Clothing also needs to be breathable, because damp clothes
> are bad at keeping the wearer warm and become very heavy. Woven
> fabrics are more breathable than fur and, when specifically tailored
> to the body, make excellent internal layers, preventing cold air from
> getting direct access to the skin’s surface. Thus the ability to
> create woven clothing would have offered ***material advantages*** to
> our early ancestors once they had left Africa for cooler climes.

[The Golden Thread: How Fabric Changed History](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=VweLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT18&lpg=PT18&dq=Thus%20the%20ability%20to%20create%20woven%20clothing%20would%20have%20offered%20material%20advantages%20to%20our%20early%20ancestors%20once%20they%20had%20left%20Africa%20for%20cooler%20areas.&source=bl&ots=uKRGIOh7G9&sig=ACfU3U0GvHM4acFZx9M-Q-Ex7WUIGflJ_Q&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi73Obb8L7xAhVIHKYKHUOfAYwQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=Thus%20the%20ability%20to%20create%20woven%20clothing%20would%20have%20offered%20material%20advantages%20to%20our%20early%20ancestors%20once%20they%20had%20left%20Africa%20for%20cooler%20areas.&f=false)

Comment: **Important**, and perhaps **practical**.

Answer (score 1):

As Kate wrote, the most generic interpretation would be "important". This is [OED entry](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/114923?rskey=Od1Jd5&result=1&isAdvanced=false#eid) 6a: "Of serious or substantial import; significant, important, of consequence."

I would also suggest "real", which is hinted at by "substantial". While it may seem like a synonym of "important", it also acts as a bridge to Kate's other suggestion of "practical". This is similar to OED entry 2b: "Concerned with matter or the physical world; involving the presence, use, or action of matter."

In plain English: the advantages of woven clothing are not just "nice to have". Woven clothing brings important, tangible, measurable benefits; it affects life in a practical, real way.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Luke Sawczak is quite correct. However, I want to add an additional point. The term "material advantage" is very often used in a specifically legal context, although that is not how the quote in the question uses it. In such a context, it can mean "physical advantage" (as opposed to emotional ot intangible advantage) and very often specifically "financial advantage". It also often means (in that context) an advantage significant enough to affect a contract, or to be worthy of legal action.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing new that Luke and Kate haven't already covered, but still if you need a close reference to the meaning, you can find it [here](https://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/material+advantage).

> 9. of great import or consequence
>
> *The new act proved to be of material advantage/benefit for the workers.*

Again, **[import](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/import)** and **[consequence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/consequence)** means the importance or significance of something.

Answer (score 0):

Material advantage comes from chess; where material refers to the number of pieces and pawns you have on the board. If you have more material than your opponent then you have a ‘material advantage’ as distinguished perhaps from a ‘positional advantage’ or ‘tactical advantage’ etc.